# Java returning Array and removing last item?

Tags: java, arrays

So im working through the coursera course for Algorithms (taught by Sedgewick, great course btw) and there is a certain part of this "unordered array priority queue that Im confused about"

```
    public class UnorderedPQ < Item extends Comparable > {
       private Comparable[] pq;
       private int N;
       public UnorderedPQ(int maxN) {
        pq = new Comparable[maxN];
       }
       public boolean isEmpty() {
        return N == 0;
       }
       public void insert(Item x) {
        pq[N++] = x;
       }
       public Item delMax() {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
         if (less(max, i)) max = i;
        exch(max, N - 1);
        return (Item) pq[--N];
       }
      }
```

`return (Item) pq[--N];` <--- this part, the comment states "remove and return max element from PQ"

So I understand basically all of it but the `pq[--N]`, keep in mind that i've basically never done any java as well.

I understand why this would return the N-1th array item....but how exactly would it remove it completely. In the course it states that we do this to "null out the entry to prevent loitering"? But im not exactly sure how that works?

sidenote: Any idea why in the for loop for delMax() we start at 1? I assume this is because we are adding into the front, so theirs no reason we'd check the first item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two questions:

1) **How does `pq[--N]` remove the item completely?** The answer is that it doesn't. It *effectively* removes it by decrementing `N`, so it won't be treated as present in the priority queue, but the reference to that `Item` is still present in the array `pq`. To completely remove it (and make it eligible for garbage collection), the array element should have been set to `null`. I would classify this as a memory leak.

2) **Why does the loop in `delMax()` start at 1?** The reason it starts at 1 is that the previous line — `int max = 0;` — sets up element 0 as the max element. There's no point in checking whether element 0 is less than itself.

Comment: I thought the --N was weird because...I mean we weren't reducing the array or anything so it seemed like it was just leaving it there.